# Counting the number of appearances of each character

Tags: c, counting

I am new to C and working on homework. I got most work done, but I can't pass all test cases that used by my professor. He refuses to post cases being used in the auto grader.

What would be the cases that I have missed?
Any clue will be appreciated!!!

```
Write a program to remove all the blank characters (space and tab) in a line. 
Then, count the number of appearances of each character.

Input
A single line with a maximum length of 5000 characters
Output
First line: The line after removing all the blank characters. 
If the line is empty, don’t print anything in the output.

Next lines: Each line contains a character that appears in the line and its count. 
Note that, the characters must appear according to their ASCII number order. (http://www.asciitable.com)
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    int  c = 0;
    int  characters[128] = {0}; //    subscripts for the ASCII table
    int  count           = 0;   //    number of characters been reading in

    while(count < 5001 && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        // 9 -> TAB on ASCII,  32 -> Space on ASCII
        if (c != 9 && c != 32) {
            putchar(c); 
            characters[c]++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
       if (characters[i] != 0) {
           printf("%c %d\n", i, characters[i]);
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Again, any help will be really appreciated!

Update:
The code has been corrected.

Comment: what is the `9` character meant to stand for?! perhaps you meant `if (!isspace(c))`.

note that the input is not interleaved with output, so you can use `putchar()` right away, no need to accumulate text into `text`

Comment: `characters[index] = 0;` Why?

Comment: @dxiv should have been `text[index] = 0` obviously :D

Comment: `characters[index] = 0;` that means that your program will write outside of the bound of the array if the length of the input is > 256 (it is supposed to be max. 5000)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Likely so, though redundant since `text` was 0-initialized.

Comment: As you've written *in the comments*, `index` is used for indexing `text`, not `characters`. Hence... not really a useful question... And your text was 0-initialized, and you were very careful to not overwrite the null terminator... and as I said above, you do not even need `text`

Comment: Think about `characters[index]`. Are you using the correct array or index there? By the way, better check the end-condition of the previous loop, are you sure that `index` will be guaranteed to be in bounds of the intended array here?

Comment: Man, I was blinded. I apologize for asking such a silly question!

Comment: @ZhihanL Don't worry, most bugs look silly *after* you've found them. I actually +1'd your question because it was clearly written and code-complete.

Comment: And please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `9` and `32` you mean the ASCII values for newline and space (respectively), please use the correct character constants `'\n' ` and `' '` instead.

Comment: Hint: you do not need the `text[]` array. You simply need to keep a count of the number of characters you read with `getchar()` and throw an error if it exceeds 5000. Your `characters[]` array need only have `128` elements. Anything above `127` isn't ASCII, but *extended ASCII*. Just read, classify, output if not whitespace and output the classification after the line.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't want to write

- ```
   characters[index] = 0;
  ```

What you want instead is probably

- ```
   text[index] = 0;
  ```